# Symfony get distinct months from database DateTime field

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Currently I have a Query Builder which gets all distinct dates from DateTime field but I need to get only distinct months and years and ignore the days. For example if dates where 2015-06-15, 2015-06-20, 2015-07-10, 2016-06-13 I should get 2015-06, 2015-07, 2016-06.

Is there any way to get this result right from database or do I need to this with php?

My current query looks like this:

```
$dates = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('EventBundle:Event')
            ->createQueryBuilder('e')
            ->select('e.startDate')
            ->where('e.startDate >= :startDate')
            ->setParameter('startDate', new DateTime('now'))
            ->orderBy('e.startDate', 'ASC')
            ->distinct()
            ->getQuery();

$dates = $dates->getResult();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it from the database but I think you will need to use a native mysql query e.g.

```
select distinct(DATE_FORMAT(e.startDate,'%Y-%m')) 
from event e 
where e.startDate >= :startDate
```

To perform a native query see [How to use Doctrine DBAL](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/dbal.html)